# "Dragging" effect for touch screen devices

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas object which once you mousedown, it will begin "sliding" the content of the canvas until you mouse up. It does not seem like mousemove is triggered for hand-held devices (my Kindle Fire).

I've noticed though that google maps is able to achieve this effect, so how do they do it? What is the accepted method for determining the position of someone dragging their finger across a canvas object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `touchmove` event. It's supported on iOS and Android.

Comment: Cool thanks. Do you have a recommendation on a good resource for reading about its implementation?